# uploading file and moving it to a folder

Tags: php, fpdf

I have a FPDF script that submits a PDF and moves it to a folder on the server.

I have a upload field in the form before the FPDF script is run named "file"

i am trying to move it to the same folder as the generated PDF.

below is my code: (the PDF is generated and moved to the folder but nothing happens with the uploaded file)

```
mkdir("claims/$name", 0777);

$move = "claims/$name";
foreach ($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"] as $key => $value) 
{
 $tmp_name = $_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key];
 $name2 = $move ."\\".basename($_FILES["files"]["name"][$key]);
 move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $name2);
}

$filename = "claims/$name/$name.pdf";
$pdf->Output($filename, 'F');
header('Location: home.php');
```

Comment: why did you create a new account?

Comment: @rtfm my brothers account. after he got negative marks he told me to make my own.

Comment: What's `"\\"` for?

Comment: @AbraCadaver im not sure actually sir. I got a friend to help me write that part as i havent done this before.

Comment: Don't let them help anymore: `$name2 = "$move/".basename($_FILES["files"]["name"][$key]);`

Comment: @AbraCadaver still the same sir. no error and only the PDF was generated. the uploaded file didnt do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working with a few changes to my code. I also got it to work with multiple uploads.

```
// make the directory
mkdir("claims/$name", 0777);

$total = count($_FILES['files']['name']);

// Loop through each file
for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) {
//Get the temp file path
$tmpFilePath = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];

//Make sure we have a filepath
if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
//Setup our new file path
$newFilePath = "claims/$name/" . $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];

//Upload the file into the temp dir
if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {

}
}
}
```